# How do I save my ubuntu sdk project to launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, ubuntu-sdk

I've got a program that I'd like to make, but I don't know how to put it on launchpad.  How do I do that?

Comment: When you get to the point of having a source tree and are able to compile a binary on your personal system, have a look at http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/. I have found the PPA guide very useful: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Answer (score 0):

Look here it is a the Bazaar 5 minutes tuto:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/mini-tutorial/index.html